# How do you group an array of movie objects based on their genre?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array of movies that have multiple genres. Using React, what is the best way to loop through that array of objects and group them by genre?

**Desired Output:**

- Action

  - Movie 1
  - Movie 2
  - Movie 5
- Crime

  - Movie 1
  - Movie 4
- Drama

  - Movie 1
  - Movie 3
  - Movie 4
- Horror

  - Movie 3
  - Movie 5

```
import _ from 'lodash'

const movieList = [
  {
    "genres": ["Action","Crime","Drama"],
    "title": "Movie 1"
  },
  {
    "genres": ["Action","Comedy"],
    "title": "Movie 2"
  },
  {
    "genres": ["Drama","Horror"],
    "title": "Movie 3"
  },
  {
    "genres": ["Crime","Drama"],
    "title": "Movie 4"
  },
  {
    "genres": ["Action","Crime","Horror"],
    "title": "Movie 5"
  }
]

export default function Home() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(movieList)
  
  return (
    // return movies listed by genre
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming data like this is what `.reduce` is for:

```
movieList.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.genres.forEach(genre => acc[genre] ? acc[genre].push(curr.title) : acc[genre] = [curr.title]);
  return acc;
}, {});
```